# Из за чего может вылетать программа при использовании QString arg?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstring

При долгом использовании программы, иногда вылетает программа в ф-ции `QString::arg`. В чем может быть дело?

---

немного кода

```
QFile *file = new QFile("log.txt");
QTextStream out;
out.setDevice(file);
//**********
```

---

В функции где происходит ошибка, выше тоже идет запись в файл. И все корректно записывается. Более того это функция записи логов. Она часто вызывается. Но иногда вылетает.

---

Иногда выводит сообщение `Critical error detected c0000374`

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Comment: судя по стэку вылетает при выделении памяти внутри строки, у вас там хватает памяти?)

Comment: предположу, что у вас здоровенная утечка памяти в проге

Comment: оперативы больше 8 гигов (50%) свободных всегда.И не хватает оперативы что бы строку из 20 символов записать в файл?

Comment: Если приложение 32 бит, то оно не может съесть более 2^32 памяти (1.4Гб), поэтому скажите, сколько памяти жрёт ваш процесс?

Comment: в пике наверное до 6ти гигов. Но сборка 64битная

Comment: ну так в пике у вас и вылетает. Это норма, что жрёт 6 гиг?

Comment: запустил на маленький объем. Но проблема осталась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось из-за неудачного перевода в enum

```
enum class EE {
    e1 = 1,
    e2,
    e3
};
QString someFunc(EE e) {
    switch(e) {
        case EE::e1: return "EE::e1";
        case EE::e2: return "EE::e2";
        case EE::e3: return "EE::e3";
    }
}

QTextStream SomeClass::operator<<(QTextStream &out, const MyStruct &r) {
    int i = 0;
    out << someFunc(EE(i)) << endl;  // тут неопределенное поведение!
    out << r.otherFields << endl;    // которая вызывала ошибку, но ниже.
}
```